# How to create own SDK for developing plugin for Desktop Application in Java?

Tags: java, swing, sdk

I am developing Swing application, and I was interested creating own SDK for extending my application through plugin. I like the way of implementing this feature in Intellij IDEA. When I googled I couldn't find any proper example of creating own SDK.

There are MenuBar, ToolBar, Widgets, and some other components in my application. I want to add some buttons to the ToolBar or menus to the MenuBar or manage other components by adding plugins or extensions. By adding I mean to add plugin or extension by choosing it via FileChooser.

How to do it in proper way?

Comment: Via dynamic class loading and a common API interface.  The plugin class would be required to implement the common API interfaces. In the past, I've used configuration files stored in the plugin jar to make determinations about what the plugin would offer and how it would work

Comment: How about attaching SDK to IDE?

Comment: Most IDEs have there own defined SDK/plugin framework, you'd have to read up on the documentation associated with the IDE

Comment: How about adding SDK as a project dependency and then compile jar without them? It should work, right?

Comment: You should first consider if you are trying to re-invent the wheel... take a look at OSGi : https://www.osgi.org/ Dynamic Module System for Java.

Comment: @Kerry Thanks for OSGi

Comment: @Xylian If you're interested in using JavaFX I have a project on GitHub that would help: https://github.com/jtkb/osgifx. See the examples module on how to use it.

Comment: You know I was reading OSGi books now, and it was a bit hard to understand, but this [OSGi modularity for JavaFX](https://github.com/jtkb/osgifx) makes it easier too learn, because I am really interested in JavaFX, Thanks, once again.